# How to know what type of cross section is it going to be?

Tags: triangles, cross-sections

A plane intersects a right rectangular pyramid. Producing a cross section. The plane is parallel to the base. What shape is the cross section? [image]

I thought it would be triangle cause triangle cut is going to be triangle right? Also I don't really understand what cross section is? How do i do these types of question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** A cross section is the shape that arises in the intersection of a plane and any solid. For example, if you cut a sphere in half, you will get a circle on the side you cut. The circle is the cross section of the sphere.

These gifs will visualize various cross sections of a cube, I hope:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: so its the blue bordered thing in the gif provided?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: @RobBland: Did you make these awesome gifs? How/where are they from?

Comment: @EliRose I did not make these, sadly. They are pretty awesome. They are from the site http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/math/4d/cube-flatland/welcome.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for these gifs, so you imagine what the thing of the shape being cut is? so if my question was of a regular cylinder it would be a circle and if it was normal pyramid would it be a triangle? what about a rectangular triangle

Comment: Well a rectangular triangle isn't a thing, for one. If your shape was a cylinder, the cross section would be a circle, yes, but only if the plane was parallel to the base of the cylinder. If it were tilted, the cross section would be an ellipse.

Comment: As for the pyramid, the cross section would be a triangle if your solid was a tetrahedron, in other words a pyramid with a triangular base.

Comment: So it would generally be the figure of the base if the cut was parallel, and also i have another question, There are so many different types of pyramid, if it says rectangular pyramid does it mean it has a rectangular base? same with triangle pyramid, it means it has a triangular base? The shapes are kind of confusing. Is their like a general idea for these?

Comment: That is correct. A rectangular pyramid, hexagonal pyramid, etc will always refer to the shape of the base of the pyramid.

Comment: so in most of the case, if it says cut parallel to the base, it is talking about the shape of the base? Thanks again

Comment: When a cut is made parallel to the base of a solid, the cross section is generally the same shape as the base, yes. This should be the last question answered in the comments, we can move this to chat if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

You cut the pyramid with a knife, horizontallly at height $z \le h$, what shape is the cut part that remains if the top is removed? Or in other words: what is the intersection, the set of common points, of  cutting plane and pyramid? If $h$ is the height of the pyramid, how does that intersection, here refered as cross section, look for different $z$, e.g $z \in \{ 1/2, h, 0, 2h, -1 \}$?

Algebraicly one can describe the cutting plane by an equation $z = c$ for some constant.

The points $(x,y,z)$ that make up the square pyramid with base length $b$ and height $h$, with its base centered at the origin, can be written as
$$
\lvert x \rvert + (b/(2h)) z \le b/2 \\
\lvert y \rvert + (b/(2h)) z \le b/2 \\
$$
Intersection means the equations for plane and pyramid must hold simultaneously, giving the conditions for the coordinates of the points of the cross section surface.